# Create a JsonWebKey from JSON

Tags: .net-core, jwt, json-web-signature

I have a url that has my jwks values.  It looks like this

```
{
  "keys": [
   {
       "kty": "RSA",
       "e": "AQAB",
       "use": "sig",
       "kid": "Has a Real Value Here",
       "alg": "RS256",
       "n": "Has a Real Value here"
   }]
}
```

I tried to take that json, and feed it into the JsonWebKey constructor like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync("https://myIdp/oauth2/jwks").Result;
var jwksString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

publicJwk = new JsonWebKey(jwksString);
```

When I do that, none of the values in the class get populated.  The thing that gets a value is a AdditionalData field.  It gets all to the json put there.

**Is there a way to get the JsonWebKey constructor to actually parse out the Json?**

Answer (score 3):

the jwks values are array so you need to you jsonwebkeyset which is an collection of jsonwebkey.
something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync("https://myIdp/oauth2/jwks").Result;
var jwksString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

jwkset = new JsonWebKeySet(jwksString);
```